# how to make multiple columns into list of key value in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

### I have a below data frame and i want to create a key value pair in list using the columns in data frame, how can i do it in python.

```
    df=
            city    code     qty1       type
             hyd     1        10          a
             hyd     2        12          b
             ban     2        15          c 
             ban     4        25          d     
             pune    1        10          e
             pune    3        12          f
```

### i want to create a new data frame as below:

```
df1 = 

city                list
hyd      [{"1":"10","type":"a"},{"2":"12","type":"b"}]
ban      [{"2":"15","type":"c"},{"4":"25","type":"d"}]
pune     [{"1":"10","type":"e"},{"3":"12","type":"f"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for t in df.itertuples():
  d[t.city].append({t.code: t.qty1, 'type': t.type})

pd.Series(d).rename_axis('city').to_frame('list')

                                              list
city                                              
ban   [{2: 15, 'type': 'c'}, {4: 25, 'type': 'd'}]
hyd   [{1: 10, 'type': 'a'}, {2: 12, 'type': 'b'}]
pune  [{1: 10, 'type': 'e'}, {3: 12, 'type': 'f'}]
```

---

#### `groupby`

```
pd.Series([
    {c: q, 'type': t}
    for c, q, t in zip(df.code, df.qty1, df.type)
]).groupby(df.city).apply(list).to_frame('list')

                                              list
city                                              
ban   [{2: 15, 'type': 'c'}, {4: 25, 'type': 'd'}]
hyd   [{1: 10, 'type': 'a'}, {2: 12, 'type': 'b'}]
pune  [{1: 10, 'type': 'e'}, {3: 12, 'type': 'f'}]
```